# Why is list(generator) differ from for i in generator?

Tags: python, generator, python-3.7

Why is generator func2(func1(init())) behaves differently depending on how i print it?

```
def func1(x):
    z = ["a", "b"]
    for i in x:
        for z1 in z:
            i["f1"] = z1
            yield i


def func2(x):
    z = ["c", "d"]
    for i in x:
        for z1 in z:
            i["f2"] = z1
            yield i


def init():
    for i in range(1, 3):
        yield {"f0": i}


def main():
    print(list(func2(func1(init()))))
    print("\n")
    for i in func2(func1(init())):
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

First print returns:

```
[{'f0': 1, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 1, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 1, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 1, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 2, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 2, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 2, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}, {'f0': 2, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}]
```

Second print returns:

```
{'f0': 1, 'f1': 'a', 'f2': 'c'}
{'f0': 1, 'f1': 'a', 'f2': 'd'}
{'f0': 1, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'c'}
{'f0': 1, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}
{'f0': 2, 'f1': 'a', 'f2': 'c'}
{'f0': 2, 'f1': 'a', 'f2': 'd'}
{'f0': 2, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'c'}
{'f0': 2, 'f1': 'b', 'f2': 'd'}
```

I also mentioned that if I change "yield i" to "yield i.copy()" printing results will match.
Is someone can explain difference?

Comment: Could you simplify the example and clarify what the difference is?

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect them to behave the same? Printing one list versus printing one separate item after the other is obviously not the same operation.

Comment: For the same reason `print([1, 2, 3])` and `for x in [1, 2, 3]: print(x)` do different things.

Comment: you are reusing dictionary i in your loops.  the inner loops for z1 in z: is pointing to the same dictionary, which gets mutated per yield, which returns the same referenced dictionary.  print(i) loop is printing them before all the property mutations are done.  list(*) is outputting after all the i["key"]= mutation side effects in the generator functions have been done.  if you used `.append` instead of print(i) you'd get the same output, although i.copy() output is probably what you want.  This is an example of one of the reasons why no-side effects and immutability is often recommended.

Comment: @user120242: This is basically the answer; why not post it as such?

Comment: Perhaps the question should be: **Why is generator func2(func1(init())) behaving differently depending on *when* I print the output?** That is, as the OP is generating a result that is being mutated as generation proceeds or after all the generators have run to completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing dictionary `i` in your loops.  The inner loops `for z1 in z:` is pointing to the same dictionary `i`, which gets mutated per yield, the yield which is returning the same referenced dictionary.
`print(i)` in the for loop is printing them before all the property mutations are done.
But, `list(*)` is outputting after all the `i["key"]=` mutation side effects in the generator functions have been done.
If you used `.append` instead of `print(i)` you'd get the same output, although `i.copy()` output is probably what you want.

This is an example of one of the reasons why no-side effects and immutability is often a recommended pattern.

```
def func1(x):
    z = ["a", "b"]
    for i in x:
        # reusing the same dictionary 'i' for multiple z1 values
        for z1 in z:
            i["f1"] = z1  # mutates i["f1"]
            yield i       # yields the same referenced dictionary for all z1 in z


def func2(x):
    z = ["c", "d"]
    for i in x:
        for z1 in z:
            i["f2"] = z1
            yield i #.copy() to fix


def init():
    for i in range(1, 3):
        yield {"f0": i}


def main():
    x = list(func2(func1(init())))
    print(x)
    x[0]['f0']='mutated'
    print(x) # notice 'mutated' affects multiple elements coinciding with an "i in x"
    print("\n")
    x = []
    for i in func2(func1(init())):
        print(i)
        x.append(i)
    x[0]['f0']='mutated'
    print(x) # notice that mutated appears in multiple elements (half of them in this case)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: I put comments on func1, because the idea is the same.  But the issue in your example code is affecting func2, because it is primarily affecting the outer loop providing dictionary references to the list() function.  Ideally you should use i.copy() on both functions (or some kind of lazy copy evaluation if you need heavy optimization) to prevent unexpected behavior, for example if you used `func1(func2(init()))`.

Note: I am mostly assuming that the second example you provided is your desired behavior, (which usually is the desired outcome).  There is valid use case for wanting the same referenced dictionary, and code like the above (usually in the context of some kind of object initialization avoidance optimization), although it makes the code harder to reason about.  Usually being able to do object reference comparison is the more useful optimization, and not having to track side-effects in your functions makes the code easier to reason.  It's especially problematic for code readability when generators are involved to have side effects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Clear explanation. I thought about mutation by myself, but that fact f0 changed value confused me. I don`t know why.

Comment: I does not wanted to have same referenced dictionary. I wanted cartesian product of arbitrary number of generators in custom way (in my program elements of product are objects of my class with specific modification rules, i choose dictionaries for simplification here). Same referenced dictionaries appeared by mistake.
Thanks again for the answer.